# Como documentar no código um hack, hotfix e qualquer situação de contorno potencialmente problemática

Tags: metodologia, documentação

Hacks, correções de urgência e qualquer situação de contorno potencialmente problemática são *um mal necessário*. Ainda que possa ser considerado opinião pessoal, ao trabalhar em equipe, pressupõe-se um mínimo de cuidado para deixar alerta para colegas, ou o próprio programador, no futuro.

Minha pergunta é: qual é o *padrão mínimo* que seria esperado de um programador para documentar um código desses no próprio código, assumindo que trabalha em uma equipe pequena, de 2 a 7 desenvolvedores.

Algo que pessoalmente faço é em um comentário, próximo aonde o problema ocorre e não no cabeçalho da função, por algo como

```
// @todo mensagem explicativa, proporcional a complexidade (nicknamedoprogrmador 2014-02-05 14:23)
```

No meu caso `@todo` pode ser trocado por `@hotfix`, porém sempre é algo comum de usar.

Ainda que essa pergunta possa ser respondida com a opinião pessoal de vocês, se houver referências para recomendações de especialistas ou de metodologias específicas ela será mais bem vinda para todos.

Comment: Ao meu ver isso depende muito da IDE utilizada. O Visual Studio, por exemplo, marca comentários como // TODO: e //HACK: em uma toolbox para fácil identificação e localização. Plugins como o Resharper também colorem e enfatizam tais linhas. Outros plugins permitem inserir tais notificações em check-ins e code reviews, para que fiquem sempre visíveis (afinal, um TODO: como comentário fica como comentário eternamente)

Comment: +1 porque achei uma pergunta muito interessante! A solução de colocar um comentário é apropriada e eu acho que o @JCKödel deveria elaborar a sugestão do Visual Studio marcar as linhas e criar uma resposta.

Comment: De todas as formas, se me permite a sugestão um pouco fora do escopo da pergunta, mais importante até do que o comentário no código é a anotação do *hack* em alguma ferramenta de controle de versão ou de fluxo de trabalho. Conforme mais tarefas se acumulam, é muito fácil esquecer as "alterações temporárias" e elas acabarem se tornando fixas...

Comment: _Problema_ de documentar fora do código um problema do código é que _em geral_ programadores não leem documentação. O escopo da minha pergunta é com o foco em _ser o realmente mínimo e imprescindível_ que qualquer pessoa deveria fazer. Além disso a maioria dos programadores já usam controle de versão, então fica fácil pegar histórico do arquivo. De qualquer forma, pessoal é livre para por sugestões além do que colocar no código fonte.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz O escopo da sua pergunta está claríssimo. E, de fato, na minha sugestão adicional eu aponto que se trata de algo *fora do escopo*. Apenas mencionei que, por mais bem documentado que um "*hotfix*" esteja no código (e sou totalmente a favor de que esteja!), alguém tem que garantir que isso seja eventualmente refeito de maneira adequada. Os programadores podem estar em outras tarefas e gerentes de projeto não costumam abrir código. Assim, se uma alteração é temporária e precisa ser repensada, ela **também** precisa de uma notificação persistente fora do contexto do código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao meu ver isso depende muito da IDE utilizada. O Visual Studio, por exemplo, marca comentários como // TODO: e //HACK: em uma toolbox para fácil identificação e localização. Plugins como o Resharper também colorem e enfatizam tais linhas. Outros plugins permitem inserir tais notificações em check-ins e code reviews, para que fiquem sempre visíveis (afinal, um TODO: como comentário fica como comentário eternamente)

Exemplo da ferramenta do VS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como ainda não teve outras respostas, vou esperar mais algum tempo antes de aprovar